# translate jquery animate code into a css3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jquery code that does what I require:

```
$("#myele").animate({left: "-120%", height: 0});
```

How could I translate this code into a css3 transition?

Comment: your code wouldn't work, this one might `$("#myele").animate ({left: "-120%", height: 0},duration)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this but i don't know why css when you have done it this way

```
#myele:hover{
    left:+="-120%";
    height:0;
}
```

Comment: are you using less? this is not pure css.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, given that the object you're animating has an initial height (other than `height: auto;`) If that's not the case, you could use `transform: scale(0);` instead of height

```
@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    100% { 
        left: -120%;
        height: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes myanimation {
    100% { 
        left: -120%;
        height: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes myanimation {
    100% { 
        left: -120%;
        height: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes myanimation {
    100% { 
        left: -120%;
        height: 0;
    }
}

#myele {
    -webkit-animation: myanimation .5s;
    -moz-animation:    myanimation .5s;
    -o-animation:      myanimation .5s;
    animation:         myanimation .5s;
}
```